# How to create routes for the following URL's in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

```
localhost/public/Products-product-name1 //Product names are alphanumeric
localhost/public/Products-product-name2
localhost/public/Products-product-name3
localhost/public/Products-product-name4
......
```

How to give single root for the url's having following prefix `Products-`

```
Route::post('Products-','ProductsController@getProducts');
```

Can anyone suggest me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could simply use [route parameters](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters):

```
Route::post('Products-{product}', 'ProductsController@getProducts');
```

and inside your controller:

```
public function getProducts($product = 'product-name1')
{
    ...
}
```